# C# WPF How do i change the content to a random button?

Tags: c#, button, random, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game in Silverlight that can be played in 1 player mode.
So for that after clicking on any button and change it's content to "X" or "O" i need to change the content of a random button.

I've tried making a list of all buttons and getting a random value:

```
    public List<string> avail = new List<string>() { "button1", "button2", "button3", "button4", "button5", "button6", "button7", "button8", "button9" };

    public string Ran()
    {
        Random b1 = new Random();
        int index = b1.Next(avail.Count); 
        if (index > 0)
            return avail[index];
        else
            return null;
    }
```

but i don't know how to make my random string a Button so i can call the following method:

```
    public void buttonchange(Button b)
    {
        if (b.Content.ToString() == "")
            if (x == true)
            {
                x = false;
                b.Content = "X";
            }
            else
            {
                x = true;
                b.Content = "O";
            }
        if(b.Name!=null)
            avail.Remove(b.Name);
    }
```

Any ideas?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of button references instead:

```
public List<Button> avail = new List<Button>() { button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9 };

public Button Ran()
{
    Random b1 = new Random();
    int index = b1.Next(avail.Count); 
    if (index > 0) {
        return avail[index];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void buttonchange(Button b)
{
    if(b != null) {
        if (b.Content.ToString() == "") {
            b.Content = x ? "X" : "O";
            x = !x;
        }
        avail.Remove(b);
    }
}
```

Not sure why the button with index zero isn't to be used, though...

Comment: i don't think there is and index 0... in index is stored avail.Count

Comment: ok good. i've tried this too. but now i get the following error message: " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property 'project.ttt.button1' " (for every element in the 'avail' List)

Please note that "button1" "button2" "button3",etc are the names of the 9 buttons that i have added manually by drag-and-drop into the ttt.xaml interface.(maybe it helps).
Thanks!

Comment: so... i have added every button in the list in the new game button clicking method. and it worked.. finally ... thanks Guffa. Hope this helps somebody else too :)